# How to handle string ordering in order by clause?

Tags: sql

Suppose I want to order the records order by a field (string data type) called `STORY_LENGTH`. This field is a multi-valued field and I represent the multiple values using commas. For example, for record1, its value is "1" and record2  its value is "1,3" and for record3 its value is "1,2". Now when, I want to order the records according to `STORY_LENGTH` then records are ordered like this `record1 > record3 > record2`. Its clear that `STORY_LENGTH` data type is string and `order by ASC` is ordering that value considering it as string. But, here comes the problem. For example, when `record4="10"` and `record5="2"` and I try to order it looks like `record4 > record5` which obviously I don't want. Because `2 > 10` and I am using a string formatted just because of multiple values of the field.
So, anybody, can you help me out of this? I need some good idea to fix.
thanks

Comment: Fix your design. Simple.

Answer (score 5):

Multi-values fields as you describe mean your data model is broken and should be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Once this is done, querying becomes much more simple.

Comment: the field will contain several value of same types. for example a song will have two lengths: 10,15 or single like 10. Currently in such a situation that db design cant be changed..

Comment: @Masud Rahman - this is unfortunate. You may want to look at a solution using the `LIKE` operator and doing string manipulation and filtering in the application, rather than the DB.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood you want to sort items by second or first number in comma separated values stored in a VARCHAR field. Implementation would depend on database used, for example in MySQL it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM stories 
ORDER BY CAST(COALESCE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(story_length, ',', -1), '0') AS INTEGER)
```

Yet it is not generally not good to use such sorting for performance reasons as sorting would require scanning of whole table instead of using index on field.

Edit: After edits it looks like you want to sort on first value and ignore value(s) after comma. As according to some comment above changes in database design are not an option just use following code for sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM stories 
ORDER BY CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(story_length, ',', 1), ''), '0') AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: thanks. It looks good. I will try with this and provide feedback